# NSView not drawn at startup (swift)

Tags: swift, xcode7

I'm trying to have a subview in a Cocoa application being drawn when the app starts up and also when a button is pressed, so I created everything in the IB and made the right outlets and actions.

In the subview I'm downloading and drawing three images, so far so good, but the only problem is that the images are displayed only whenever I resize the window.

I tried resetting the needsDisplay attribute for the original view when i draw the pictures but it doesn't seem to work.
On top of that sometimes I see some wobbly glitches when i resize the window (I'm using autolayout to rescale the plots accordingly but every now and then they shrink to 0 pixels and then they go back to the intended size).

This is my first swift project, so it's probably less than optimal, but if anyone has an idea why it's not working that would be much appreciated.

edit: I had pasted the wrong link, this one should work
https://www.dropbox.com/s/yf9m9vpxckjvfsv/Cnaf-monitor.zip?dl=0

I did most of the project in the IB, the only part where I had to put some code was the ViewController.swift

```
import Cocoa

class ViewController: NSViewController {
// MARK: Properties

@IBOutlet weak var Image1: NSImageCell!
@IBOutlet weak var Image2: NSImageCell!
@IBOutlet weak var Image3: NSImageCell!
@IBOutlet weak var SbView1: NSView!
@IBOutlet weak var LastUp: NSTextFieldCell!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    //        self.view.wantsLayer = true
    //        self.SbView1.wantsLayer = true  
}

override func viewWillAppear() {
}

override var representedObject: AnyObject? {
    didSet {
    // Update the view, if already loaded.
    //            self.SbView1.layer?.backgroundColor = NSColor.whiteColor().CGColor
        refreshPlots()
    }
}

// MARK: Actions
@IBAction func refreshPlotsAction(sender: NSButton) {
    refreshPlots()
}


//get data from URL
func getDataFromUrl(url:NSURL, completion: ((data: NSData?, response: NSURLResponse?, error: NSError? ) -> Void)) {
    NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(url) { (data, response, error) in
        completion(data: data, response: response, error: error)
        }.resume()
}


//download image
func downloadImage(url: NSURL, image: NSImageCell){
    print("Download Started")
    print("lastPathComponent: " + (url.lastPathComponent ?? ""))
    getDataFromUrl(url) { (data, response, error)  in
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) { () -> Void in
            guard let data = data where error == nil else { return }
            print(response?.suggestedFilename ?? "")
            print("Download Finished")
            image.image = NSImage(data: data)
            //                Image1.image = NSImage(data: data)
        }
    }
}

func refreshPlots() {
    //Building the URL string...
    let baseUrl = "http://tier1.cnaf.infn.it/monitor/monitoring/all/"
    let date = NSDate()
    let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
    let components = calendar.components(NSCalendarUnit.Year.union(NSCalendarUnit.Month).union(NSCalendarUnit.Day).union(NSCalendarUnit.Hour).union(NSCalendarUnit.Minute), fromDate: date)
    let string1 = String(components.year) + String(format: "%02i", components.month) + String(format: "%02i", components.day-1) + String(format: "%02i", components.hour) + String(format: "%02i", components.minute)
    let string2 = String(components.year) + String(format: "%02i", components.month) + String(format: "%02i", components.day) + String(format: "%02i", components.hour) + String(format: "%02i", components.minute)
    print(string1 + "-" + string2)

    if let checkedUrl = NSURL(string: baseUrl+"ams_short/"+string1+"-"+string2+".jobs-800x600.png"){
        downloadImage(checkedUrl, image: self.Image1)
    }

    if let checkedUrl = NSURL(string: baseUrl+"ams/"+string1+"-"+string2+".jobs-800x600.png"){
        downloadImage(checkedUrl, image: self.Image2)
    }

    if let checkedUrl = NSURL(string: baseUrl+"ams_prod/"+string1+"-"+string2+".jobs-800x600.png"){
        downloadImage(checkedUrl, image: self.Image3)
    }
    self.LastUp.title = "Last update: " + String(format: "%02i", components.hour) + ":" + String(format: "%02i", components.minute) + " - " + String(format: "%02i", components.day) + "/" + String(format: "%02i", components.month) + "/" + String(format: "%02i", components.year)
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {self.view.needsDisplay = true})

}


}
```

Comment: you didn't provide the full project, files are missing

Comment: just show the code for adding the subviews and the subview code.

Comment: my bad the link should be fixed now, I also added the code in ViewController.swift